# Proper use of use-package

Tags: package, use-package

I am using the following init file to download and load packages from melpa-stable in fresh Emacs installations:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))
(setq use-package-always-pin  "melpa-stable")
(package-initialize)

;; Download use-package
(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))

;; Reduce load time
(eval-when-compile (require 'use-package))

;; Get packages
(use-package foo :ensure t)

;;... etc
```

I have two questions/problems.

First: `(eval-when-compile (require 'use-package))` is  suggested by [github.com/jwiegley/use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package), to speed-up the init, but to me it gives the  non-critical error:

```
Eager macro-expansion failure: (file-missing "Cannot open load file" "No such file or directory" "use-package")
```

Secondly, while use-package is proposes a safe approach to automatically install packages, the author does not tell how to do same with use-package itself. The test `(package-installed-p 'use-package)` works, but since it requires initialising all packages, I suspect it can slow-down the init, and wonder if there is a faster way.

### Edit

It seems that after switching from  `https://stable.melpa.org/packages` to `https://melpa.org/packages` the eager macro-expansion failure disappeared from the  Messages buffer.

Comment: Is `use-package.el` in your `load-path`? Did you install package `use-package`?

Comment: @Drew: Not in a fresh Emacs. My point is to auto-install it, just like I  auto-install the other packages with use-package `ensure`.

Comment: FYI, jwiegley doesn't use package.el to install packages at all, and `use-package` wasn't originally written to work with it (that was retrofitted by others afterwards). https://github.com/jwiegley/dot-emacs

Comment: @npostavs: Thanks, I just saw and I don't understand how he installs `use-package`, maybe some bash script

Comment: I'm using the same bootstrap method, and don't get your error. Also, it takes about 12 seconds (by dumb counting) to bootstrap a "fresh" setup, and less 1 second to subsequently start `emacs` for me.